# Powershell, Linq, Html: change background to entire ror

Tags: html, xml, linq, powershell

The follow code is able to change background to a certain cell, but I need to change the backgrond color to entire row.

This is a way to do this?

TNX

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

# Get the running processes to x(ht)ml
$xml = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse( "$(Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html)" )

# Find the index of the column you want to format:
$wsIndex = (($xml.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}th") | Where-Object {             $_.Value -eq "WS" }).NodesBeforeSelf() | Measure-Object).Count

# Format the column based on whatever rules you have:
switch($xml.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}td") | Where {     ($_.NodesBeforeSelf() | Measure).Count -eq $wsIndex } ) {
{200MB -lt $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: red;"); continue } 
{20MB  -lt $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: orange;"); continue    } 
{10MB  -lt $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: yellow;"); continue   } 
 }
 # Save the html out to a file
$xml.Save("c:\procs2.html")

# Open the thing in your browser to see what we've wrought
ii c:\procs2.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical(and working) solution here would be to get the parent element of each `td` cell in the loop, which is the whole row (`tr`).

Replace the three:

```
$_.SetAttributeValue(
```

with

```
$_.Parent.SetAttributeValue(
```

You should take some time and actually learn PowerShell, maybe a little HTML and searching with Google. If you had searched for the `Descendants` method for `XDocument`, you would see that it returns an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which MSDN says has a `Parent` property.

UPDATE: Here's YOUR script with my single update in the three locations. It works perfectly here. The whole row gets colored.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

# Get the running processes to x(ht)ml
$xml = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse( "$(Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html)" )

# Find the index of the column you want to format:
$wsIndex = (($xml.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}th") | Where-Object {             $_.Value -eq "WS" }).NodesBeforeSelf() | Measure-Object).Count

# Format the column based on whatever rules you have:
switch($xml.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}td") | Where {     ($_.NodesBeforeSelf() | Measure).Count -eq $wsIndex } ) {
{200MB -lt $_.Value } { $_.Parent.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: red;"); continue } 
{20MB  -lt $_.Value } { $_.Parent.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: orange;"); continue    } 
{10MB  -lt $_.Value } { $_.Parent.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: yellow;"); continue   } 
 }
 # Save the html out to a file
$xml.Save("c:\procs2.html")

# Open the thing in your browser to see what we've wrought
ii c:\procs2.html
```

Comment: I'm not a Developer but I only need to make a little script.
I like to learn new things and naturally I have Googled before posting.
BTW $_.Parent.SetAttributeValue() not work.
Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: Now works also in my more complex script.
Thank You.